# How to sense voltage of 48 V 600 Ah VRLA battery bank for Arduino

Tags: voltage, batteries, sensor, power-electronics

How to check the battery terminal voltage across 48 V (2* 24 V cells) of VRLA battery bank (600 Ah). I am not sure whether a voltage divider serves the purpose. Please give me the advice to convert it to 5 V (Arduino compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voltage divider should do fine. As long as you have no load on the divider and are using it to only read the battery voltage then you will be fine.

If you use the divider equation of Vdiv = Vin*(R2/R1+R2) then you can choose your own resistor values to give yourself a readable voltage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use a wire wound resistor? and what should be the wattage of the resistors?

Comment: There is a load of 100A.

Comment: There won't be a load of 100A on the voltage divider though I would assume. You would divide the battery voltage with the resistors and that would be fed straight into the Arduino pin. So there would not be a 100A load in this divider so it would be fine. The current through the divider will just be a simple I=V/R

Comment: It is a telephone exchange and the working  equipments are drawing around 100A. I would like to sense the battery voltage without the working of telephone exchange.

Comment: Yes, the load of the *battery* is drawing 100A, but the voltage divider will not have 100A going through it, as the load is not on the voltage out of the divider. If you are still confused, you will need to add a schematic into your question so that it can be looked at more thoroughly

Comment: I have got the point. Thank you for your great help :) I am trying to send the battery voltage via the internet to some mobile devices. now I am In the very beginning stage of the project.

Comment: No problem. Glad you managed to get it eventually. sometimes it takes a while then it just sinks in! Remember to accept the answer if I gave you the correct information and it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: You saved my day!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can click the tick (underneath the up/down arrows) to mark an answer as accepted if it was correct.